# Add 2.x together with 5.x verison of iText to the classpath

Tags: jasper-reports, itext

I would like to add 2 versions of iText (2.x and 5.x) in the classpath. As far as I saw, they have different packages, so I assume, that it should work fine.

Are there any known problems with this setup?

I want to make this mostly because we have existing classes using iText 5.x, but I now want to use JasperReports (in addition to existing stuff), which require iText version 2.x.

Comment: The iText versions can coexist but some dependencies may cause problems, namely BouncyCastle 1.46 (for iText 2.x) and 1.47 (for iText trunk). Thus, security provider related features might be hampered.

Comment: @mkl And if that is the case, we use the Android-GAE port of iText that has a dependency on SpongyCastle instead of BouncyCastle.

Comment: @mkl Thanks for the comment. Can you please create complete answer from it, so that I can accept it. BTW, I tested it, and it really works without any problems :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iText versions can coexist but some dependencies may cause problems, namely BouncyCastle 1.46 and earlier (for iText 2.x) and 1.47 or meanwhile even 1.48 (for iText trunk). Thus, security provider related features might be hampered.

If that is an issue for you, simply use the Android-GAE port of iText that has a dependency on SpongyCastle instead of BouncyCastle as indicated by @BrunoLowagie. SpongyCastle is a BouncyCastle spin-off with a different package structure to allow for different BC flavours to be used at the same time